# Flutter version compatibility error in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-mapbox-gl

I am new to Flutter and tried to clone a Flutter app from GitHub but I am getting some version errors, I tried to solve it with my knowledge but I can't do it properly.

Please have a look on my error :

---

```
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.2.

Because get 3.26.0 doesn't support null safety and no versions of get match >3.26.0 <4.0.0, get ^3.26.0 is forbidden.
So, because boxtox depends on get ^3.26.0, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.9.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
```

---

And here is my dependencies :

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.13.5"
```

I just tried to run it on my system. but it's not working and throwing the error which i have mentioned.

Comment: In Flutter cloned app, just update the version of get (https://pub.dev/packages/get) plugin.